# Custom style for dialog or disable inheriting of activity style

Tags: android

Im trying to set my custom style for dialog because dialog inherit style from activity where is padding set to 10 dpi. But everything what i tried failed :).

style:

```
<style name="ActivityStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

dialog style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/CreateRoomDialog_textName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CreateRoomDialog_fieldName"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="38dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/CreateRoomDialog_textPwd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CreateRoomDialog_fieldPwd"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="38dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CreateRoomDialog_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CreateRoomDialog_btnOK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom dialog consturctor:

```
public CreateRoomDialog(Context c, boolean isNew) {
        super(c); - I tried put style here, but no success.

        this.c = c;
        this.isNew = isNew;

        this.setTitle(c.getString(R.string.CreateRoomDialog_addData));
        setContentView(R.layout.createroomdialog);

    }
```

with padding it looks like:

[image: with padding]

without padding dialog is ok, but activity doesnt:

[image: without padding]

Comment: Where did you apply `ActivityDialog` style to your dialog? I couldn't find it!

Comment: Sorry its bad name for style. Its style for activity, which is applied in manifest.

Comment: What about if you add `style="@style/ActivityDialog"` to your `layout_root`?

Comment: Its not working exactly as I want. Dialog and padding is ok, but it not showing transparent background behind activity. But thank you for your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I removed padding from style, so dialog not inherit padding. And I add padding to each activity layout manually.